# Difficulty Echoing JPEG Images

Tags: php

I'm having some difficulties echoing images to the browser. I'm quite new to PHP and I've been searching around the web for the past hour without finding a solution. I have tried adding `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`
 to the document but it does nothing. I want my code to scan the directory and put all of its image files into the $thumbArray which I will echo to the browser. My ultimate goal is a photo gallery. Getting the images into the array works fine, but it will not display them on the page. Here is my my code:

```
  <?php

//Directory that contains the photos
$dir = 'PhotoDir/';

//Check to make sure the directory path is valid
if(is_dir($dir))
{
    //Scandir returns an array of all the files in the directory
    $files = scandir($dir);
}



//Declare array
$thumbArray = Array();

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..")     //Check that the files are images
        array_push($thumbArray, $file);   //array_push will add the $file to thumbarray at index count - 1
}


 print_r($thumbArray);


include 'gallery.html';

?>
```

Heres the Gallery.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>


    <?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 

    for($i = 0; $i < count($thumbArray); $i++)
     echo '<img src="$dir'.$thumbArray[$i].'" alt="Picture" />';

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `'<img src="' . $dir . $thumbArray[$i] . '" />'`

Comment: Replacing my line with yours doesn't fix my issue. I still see the tiny square box with the folded corner page instead of my image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your current case, just remove `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` from your code. Your output is HTML. All images are output inside `IMG` tags. No additional header modifications is required in this case.

Also, if you want use PHP, do not put this code in *.html file. It will not run inside *.html with default http-server's settings. Rename `gallery.html` to the `gallery.php` and change `include 'gallery.html';` to the `include 'gallery.php';` and it will works fine (of course if you have removed `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` also).

Third bad thing is:

```
echo '<img src="$dir'.$thumbArray[$i].'" alt="Picture" />';
```

You're trying to put `$dir` variable into single quote. Only double quote allows you to use PHP variables inside.

Change it:

```
echo '<img src="'.$dir.$thumbArray[$i].'" alt="Picture" />';
```

After changing, please, look in source code of the page and check if your image path is correct. If no, do something for correcting it. For example, maybe you forgot about directory separator and correct string will be:

```
echo '<img src="'.$dir.'/'.$thumbArray[$i].'" alt="Picture" />';
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you! It's now working perfectly! Just curious, when is it required to specify the header type?

Comment: @Whoppa, if your output is raw JPEG (binary JPEG file content), PDF, PNG, or any file which is not HTML, you need to set up additional headers. Otherwise no.